# How to check the current queue depth value?

Tags: redhat, storage-area-network, hard-drive, fibre-channel, netapp

I have an OEL server connected via fibre to a NetApp SAN. How can I view the queue depth as the OS sees it?

Output from  `lspci`:

```
05:00.0 Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)
05:00.1 Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)
08:00.0 Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)
08:00.1 Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)
```

Output from `lsmod`:

```
qla2xxx              1262209  352
scsi_transport_fc      83145  1 qla2xxx
scsi_mod              199641  15 be2iscsi,ib_iser,iscsi_tcp,bnx2i,libcxgbi,libiscsi2,scsi_transport_iscsi2,scsi_dh,sr_mod,sg,qla2xxx,scsi_transport_fc,libata,cciss,sd_mod
```

`ls /sys/class/fc_host/host*`

```
/sys/class/fc_host/host3:
device       issue_lip  port_id    port_state  speed       subsystem          supported_speeds  system_hostname  uevent
fabric_name  node_name  port_name  port_type   statistics  supported_classes  symbolic_name     tgtid_bind_type

/sys/class/fc_host/host4:
device       issue_lip  port_id    port_state  speed       subsystem          supported_speeds  system_hostname  uevent
fabric_name  node_name  port_name  port_type   statistics  supported_classes  symbolic_name     tgtid_bind_type

/sys/class/fc_host/host5:
device       issue_lip  port_id    port_state  speed       subsystem          supported_speeds  system_hostname  uevent
fabric_name  node_name  port_name  port_type   statistics  supported_classes  symbolic_name     tgtid_bind_type

/sys/class/fc_host/host6:
device       issue_lip  port_id    port_state  speed       subsystem          supported_speeds  system_hostname  uevent
fabric_name  node_name  port_name  port_type   statistics  supported_classes  symbolic_name     tgtid_bind_type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On mine to NETAPP:

```
ls /proc/scsi/qla2xxx
1
ls /proc/scsi/qla2xxx/1 | grep -i -A1 -B1 "queue depth"
Total number of interrupts = 30686605
    Device queue depth = 0x20
Number of free request entries = 1842
```

So x20 is 32 in decimal,
This is the # you are looking for.
You can read about calculation for NETAPP here:

https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1196793/html/GUID-A055B184-0876-4376-9C75-35FE8C9BE832.html

EDIT:
some other method to see:
`cat /sys/module/qla2xxx/parameters/ql2xmaxqdepth`

Comment: I do not have anything like that in /proc/scsi. I have `cciss`  `device_info`  `scsi` and `sg`.

Comment: what again is your output?

Comment: I don't have any output because I don't have anything under /proc/scsi that is like `qla2xxx`

Comment: what is your FC controller? mine just happens to be QLogic.

Comment: lsmod |grep qla

qla2xxx              1262209  352
scsi_transport_fc      83145  1 qla2xxx
scsi_mod              199641  15 be2iscsi,ib_iser,iscsi_tcp,bnx2i,libcxgbi,libiscsi2,scsi_transport_iscsi2,scsi_dh,sr_mod,sg,qla2xxx,scsi_transport_fc,libata,cciss,sd_mo
d http://pastebin.com/XvLtePRP

Comment: Can you see with lspci?

Comment: 05:00.0 Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)
05:00.1 Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)
08:00.0 Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)
08:00.1 Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)

Comment: ls /sys/class/fc_host/host*

Comment: Add all that info into question please, so I people could see as well.

Comment: Sorry, the question is now updated. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: "systool -c scsi_host -v" this will give you some info. Also "lsscsi -l" should tell queue depth.

Comment: The `systool` command does not show the queue depth. I do not have `lsscsi`. Is this a tool you installed separately on your system?

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way is

```
cat /sys/block/<sdX>/device/queue_depth
```